# How to scale the axis in Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a data set that has two tab delimited columns that I plot in a simple XY axis. The independent variable (x axis) is duration in minutes. What I want is to plot this in hours instead of minutes. How would I apply this scaling in gnuplot while plotting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164052/gnuplot-v4-4-problem-plotting-using-timeseries-x-axis); perhaps it will help.

In your case I expect you want something like

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%M"
set format x "%H:%M"
```

These commands tell gnuplot you are providing timedata in the form of minutes,
but you want them displayed with hours and minutes.

EDIT (see comments): (ignoring the time formatting)  Scaling the axis of a data file `data.dat` can be achieved as follows:

```
plot "data.dat" using ($1/60):2 with lines
```

The `$1` is the column that you want to scale, which you manipulate with maths operations.
You usually need to wrap the whole expression in parenthesis before the moving onto other columns.

Comment: my problem is actually quite simple than this I think. The duration column is already in the minute form (12.00, 15.00, 20.50 etc.). What I want is just to be able to plot this by scaling this by 60 (for hours).

Comment: I'm not certain what you mean.  If you mean "divide the x column by 60" then you can do this as follows: "plot "./data.dat" using ($1/60):2 with line.  If you want 74 to be displayed as 01:14 then the above answer is what you want