# How to scale the axes in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, axes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to scale the axis in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204839/how-to-scale-the-axis-in-gnuplot)

I have the x and y axes with large numbers (1000, 2000, etc.) But I wish to re-write or re-scale these without changing or rescaling the data, such that 1000 is 1 in the axis, etc. I'm not looking for 1x10^3. Just letting 1000 be 1. Is there any way I could do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is rescale the data on input:

```
plot 'datafile' using ($1/1000.):2  #assume x-data is in first column
```

Now as far as gnuplot is concerned, you gave it 1., not 1000.