# How to format x axis to a smaller scale?

Tags: gnuplot, axes

So here is what I'm trying to do.
The values on x axis are from 10000, 20000, 30000, ... 100000. I'm trying to write it like this: 10, 20, 30, 40, ... 100 (only x axis)

Is there some way to do this in Gnuplot?

I have this so far:
(data.dat - example of data)

```
# x       y
10000 +1.24241522E-04
11000 +1.28623514E-04
12000 +1.35229020E-04
13000 +1.43767741E-04
14000 +1.53409148E-04
15000 +1.63788695E-04
16000 +1.75429485E-04
17000 +1.88827813E-04
18000 +2.02984785E-04
19000 +2.20830420E-04
...
```

(my gnuplot script)

```
set term png

set out 'example.png'

U0 = 0.00732     #parameters for this particular problem
v1 = 68000
b1 = 6550
v2 = 59600
b2 = 6050
I = sqrt(-1)

A(w, w0, b) = ((w0)**2)/(((w0)**2) - ((w)**2) + 2*I*w*b)

f(x) = U0*abs(A(2*pi*x, 2*pi*v1, b1) - A(2*pi*x, 2*pi*v2, b2))

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

fit f(x) 'data.dat' u 1:2 via U0, v1, b1, v2, b2

plot 'data.dat' u 1:2 t "Title1" w p, U(x) t "Title2"

set out
```

[image]

But how do I do this?
I've tried this example 
[How to scale the axes in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11509088/how-to-scale-the-axes-in-gnuplot#11509603) 
but it doesn't work.
See below.

```
# I modified the things a little bit

f(x) = (.... ... ....)/1000

fit f(x) 'data.dat' u ($1/1000.):2 via U0, v1, b1, v2, b2

plot 'data.dat' u ($1/1000.):2 t "Title1" w p, f(x) t "Title2"
```

But now the fitted function disappears!

How can I modify x-axis without other function disappearing?

[image]

Does there exist a line command in gnuplot for this? I'm sure there has to be a more elegant way of writing this insted of dividing each function by a desired factor.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What's wrong with the answer in the second link? What is your code so far?

Comment: @theozh I edited my post so it's clearer what I'm trying to do.

Comment: cant you devide it `// 10000`, or change you bin size? notice, use `//` to get a `integer`

Comment: What are the original values in your `data.dat`? Please show a few example lines. What is `f(x)`? Please give a minimal reproducible example. Please code as text, not as screenshot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @The.B `//` does not exist in gnuplot. In gnuplot `/` is integer division if both numbers are integers. This often leads to confusion and unexpected results. Furthermore, `$1` is always interpreted as floating point number, so `$1/1000` is fine and the `.` in `$1/1000.` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible ways come to my mind:

1. if you want to avoid too many zeros in the xtic labels, simply set the xtic label format to engineering

   `set format x "%.0s%c"`

   This will show, e.g.  10000 and 100000 as 10k and 100k, respectively.
2. if you scale (in your case: divide) the x values of the data by factor of 1000, gnuplot will take this x range for plotting the function `f(x)`. Since this is will give x values which are a factor of 1000 too small you have to scale your x values by a factor of 1000 accordingly (in your case: multiply).

**Code:**

```
### avoid too many zeros in xtic labels
reset session

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    A = rand(0)*10+5
    B = rand(0)*50000+25000
    C = rand(0)*5000+5000
    do for [i=10000:100000:500] {
        print sprintf("%g %g",i,A*exp(-((real(i)-B)/C)**2))
    }
set print

a=1; b=50000; c=5000          # give some reasonable starting values
f(x) = a*exp(-((x-b)/c)**2)
set fit quiet nolog
fit f(x) $Data u 1:2 via a,b,c

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set format x "%.0s%c"      # set xtics to engineering
    plot $Data u 1:2 w p, \
         f(x) w l lc "red"

    set format x "%g"          # set xtics to default
    plot $Data u ($1/1000):2 w p, \
         f(x*1000) w l lc "red"

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]