# How to rescale x axis when plotting a function in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've already seen [How to scale the axis in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204839/how-to-scale-the-axis-in-gnuplot), but I'm not sure how this would work with a function such as

```
set xrange[-10:10]
f(x) = x**2
plot f(x)
```

My actual function isn't so easily rescaled as the one above.  All I want to do is change the units on the x axis from metres (which is what f(x) accepts), to kilometres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your function definition `f(x)` needs metre and you want your x-axis to display kilometres, then you must scale x by 1000:

```
set xlabel 'kilometres'
set xrange [-0.01:0.01]
f(x) = x**2
plot f(1000*x)
```