# start of X series

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to know how to set x axis to start drawing at the first point of data, instead of the first day of date-range?.

(too bad I can't post pictures because I don't have the 10 points)

Comment: Hi Leonardo, I think you'll need to specify your question a little. Unless someone else had the very same problem I don't think your question can be understood. Maybe it would help, if you post some example gnuplot code or data file and point out in what aspects the plot should differ.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it seems that you want to set the x-range in a time-series (this is a guess - it would help if you wrote the gnuplot code that you are using).

You can do this like so:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S" 
set xrange["26/10/2010 13:00:00":"26/10/2010 14:00:00"]
```

Notice that the `xrange` must be written in the same way as the `timefmt`.

See [gnuplot v4.4: Problem plotting using timeseries x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164052/gnuplot-v4-4-problem-plotting-using-timeseries-x-axis/4164684#4164684) for more info.